# Merge [chart.js] into [chartjs]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The tags [chartjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chartjs) and [chart.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chart.js) are either identical or indistinguishable.

I recommend keeping [chartjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chartjs) as it has more questions and its tag wiki is more verbose.

1. [chartjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chartjs) - 290 questions, 28 followers
2. [chart.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chart.js) - 63 questions, 2 followers

Comment: Merge, not burninate?

Comment: sorry, yes. i'm not familiar with the tag cleanup process.

Comment: I'd say `chart.js` fits the pattern of other JS libraries much better. Why not create a synonym instead? Propose `chartjs` as a synonym of `chart.js`, and all questions with `chartjs` will be automatically retagged to `chart.js`. Problem solved.

Comment: i don't know if there is a standard. for instance, `angular.js`'s tag is just `angularjs` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs

Comment: You can always copy across the tag wiki if that's better on one than the other.

Comment: @DLeh: ah, it is about [50-50](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/285597). Still, I prefer the spelling with a dot.

Comment: wow, 193:196. tight race! merging this one would take it to 194-195!

Comment: @DLeh: no, 192:196.

Comment: I just proposed chart.js as a synonym for chartjs and am twiddling my thumbs waiting for it to get enough upvotes. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/chartjs/synonyms :-)

Comment: @DLeh http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/charts.js should be a synonym as well.

Answer (score 2):

It appears as though they go by [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/), so I think we should keep [chart.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chart.js) as the base.

Because there are 290 questions we should wait for a mod to merge the two tags ([chartjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chartjs) into [chart.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chart.js)) instead of retagging them manually. It doesn't need a synonym, as the tag can't be recreated after it is merged.